# PHP - Undefined variable config?

Tags: php, configuration

So I have a config file, config_inc.php:

```
<?php
static $config = Array();
$config['dbHost'] = 'localhost';
$config['dbPass'] = '';
$config['dbUser'] = 'root';
$config['dbName'] = 'recipes_comments';
?>
```

And then I have a controller which is supposed to load these variables using require_once:

```
require_once "config_inc.php";
class Controller {
public function regUser() {
echo $config['dbHost'];
}
}
```

I tried to find posts with similar errors, but could not find one that provides a solution that fixes this.

When I try to echo a variable defined in config_inc.php as shown above, I get an error that config is undefined.

**My question: Why is config not defined in Controller and what's the proper way to do this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Require\_once inside a class construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112664/php-require-once-inside-a-class-construct)

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275931/null-variable-in-php-class).

Answer (score 2):

config is not defined in Controller because it's not global.

**The Bad Way**
You first have to replace `static` by `global` in your config file, then add `global $config` at the beginning of your function.

**The proper Way**
Don't use global in php. Instead, pass your `$config` array in the constructor of your class, or add it in an other way. For example

```
require_once "config_inc.php";

class Controller {
  private $config;
  public function regUser() {
    echo $this->config['dbHost'];
  }
  public function __construct($config)
  { 
    $this->config = $config;
  }
}

$controller = new Controller($config);
$controller->regUser();
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a scope issue. You are trying to access to a variable that your class can't see from his scope.

$config is a global variable in your code. That mean, he exist in the global scope.

try this:

```
require_once "config_inc.php";
class Controller {
    public function regUser() {
        echo $GLOBALS['$config']['dbHost'];
    }
}
```